# A Lot of WordPress wp-cron.php in Memory

Tags: wordpress, shared-hosting

My client is hosting many WordPress blogs. I checked system load with "ps -ef | grep -i php" (because the server is hosting domains for clients using SuPHP and cpanel) and I see many of the blogs have wp-cron.php in memory, sometimes several of the same domain running several copies of wp-cron.php.

Is this wp-cron.php loaded so much a normal thing with WordPress? Or is it a misconfiguration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your shared hosting platform doesn't allow you to run cronjobs than wp-cron.php serves that purpose. It fires off routinely to perform tasks that need to be done that would normally be run via cron. As cron isn't running it calls wp-cron.php more often to ensure that the tasks are ran. Unless your being told you're account is using too much memory, which if running under SuPHP it should already limit you, then you should have no problem. I run two WP blogs on a clustered shared-hosting platform and it's never a problem. When I look through my logs I do see lots of calls to wp-cron.php and everything is all good.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal, yes.

I have that process running frequently myself.